# Why did I need to wrap the state in brackets to assign it to a variable in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, arrays, state, push, brackets

I was trying to build a simple Todo App with a currentTodo and an array of pastTodos.

I was unable to push currentTodo to pastTodo using this code here.

```
  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let pastTodos = this.state.pastTodos;
    pastTodos.push(this.state.currentTodo);
    this.setState({ pastTodos: pastTodos, currentTodo: "" });
  }
```

and was only able to do by changing this line

```
let pastTodos = this.state.pastTodos;
```

to this

```
let pastTodos = [this.state.pastTodos];
```

Why would this be? And is this the best way to do this?

Below is all of my code for greater context.

```
import React from 'react';

class TodoInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentTodo: "", 
      pastTodos: []
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const currentTodo = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ currentTodo: currentTodo})
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let pastTodos = [this.state.pastTodos];
    pastTodos.push(this.state.currentTodo);
    this.setState({ pastTodos: pastTodos, currentTodo: "" });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" value={this.state.currentTodo}/>
        <br></br>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Add Todo </button>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
}

export default TodoInput;
```

Comment: At a broad level one possible response is simply that you can't (or at least really, really shouldn't) mutate state values in React.  Instead, you use them to create new state values and update the state with those new values.  However, it's possible something else is also happening here, because those two lines of code do very different things.  One initialized `pastTodos` to the value of `this.state.pastTodos`, while the other initializes `pastTodos` to *an array* in which the *only element* is the value of `this.state.pastTodos`.  So... One results in an array, one does not.

Comment: hmmm, thats interesting. I'll definitely avoid mutating state in the future. In regards to your bottom comment, wouldn't the line without the brackets still be an array since I initialized that part of state to empty brackets in the constructor?

Comment: In that case what you're creating in the "working" version is an array containing an array, so basically this: `[[]]`  Then pushing a value to it results in: `[[], someValue]`  Doing it again: `[[[], someValue], anotherValue]`  And again: `[[[[], someValue], anotherValue], andAnother]`  It's basically wrapping each array in a new array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt this is "working":

```
let pastTodos = [this.state.pastTodos];
```

At the very least, it's probably producing a bug you haven't noticed yet.  Because this is creating a new array with only one element, that element being the value of `this.state.pastTodos`.

For example, look at the initial value of that state:

```
pastTodos: []
```

So what are you updating it to?  this:

```
let pastTodos = [[]];
```

Then you push a value to it, resulting in this:

```
[[], someValue]
```

If you perform that operation again, you get this:

```
[[[], someValue], anotherValue]
```

This *probably* isn't the structure you want.

---

At a high level, you don't want to mutate state in React.  Doing this with an array:

```
let pastTodos = this.state.pastTodos;
```

Just creates another reference to the same array.  And then you mutate that array:

```
pastTodos.push(this.state.currentTodo);
```

Instead of creating a reference to the same array, create a *new* array:

```
let pastTodos = [...this.state.pastTodos];
```

This creates a brand new array and uses [the spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to populate it with the *items* of the array in state.  Now you're not modifying that state array but rather just modyfing a locally defined array here:

```
pastTodos.push(this.state.currentTodo);
```

Then you can use that locally defined array to update state as you currently do.

Comment: In case you are like me and still learning JS concepts as you learn react, i'll add this commentary to the above solution: the ‘…’ above is called the Spread operator and it just does Object.assign
Here is documentation for spread: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax
Here is documentation for assign: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign